# I'm getting a ValueError: cannot convert string to float: ".". What is going on?

Tags: python, valueerror

I am trying to write a function that takes in a file with numerical values, total them all up while excluding all numbers with a letter, and find the average. However, when I try to convert a number like "3.9" to float form, I get the ValueError: cannot convert string to float: ".". I know that if I just did a straight conversion of "3.9" to float form via float("3.9") type casting it would work.

```
def averageSpeed():
    count = 0
    total = 0
    stripLst = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz$'
    while count < 2:
        try:
            filename = input("Enter a file to process: ")
            instance = open(filename, "r")
            content = instance.readlines()
            for line in content:
                lineSplit = line.split()
                for element in lineSplit:
                    for letter in element:
                        for character in stripLst:
                            if letter == character:
                                lineSplit.remove(element)
            for line in content:
                for element in line:
                    if float(element) > 2:
                        total += float(element)
                print(lineSplit)
            average = total / count
            print(average)
            break
        except (FileNotFoundError):
            print("That file does not exist.")
            count += 1
            filename = input("Enter a file name that exists: ")

averageSpeed()
```

File contents:
35.2
1.8
65.6
67.9z
70.2
73.2 a3.9 65.6 69.8
6$4.9
54.9

Comment: the problem is in the first for loop block you aren't really changing anything in content which you later access in the second loop, which because the original list contents aren't formatted you would still have all of the formatting issues in the original content. secondly, you first access the element in the line and then access each individual character of that line (wich when going through the line item by item you will have an error) as characters won't always be floats.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Okay, so, you're getting an error message, and the message tells you that there is a problem with taking in a string `"."` and converting it to float. Right? So. **Did you expect** the string to be like that (i.e., it **only** contains a decimal point, and nothing else)? If you did: *what do you think should be the result* of converting to float, and why? Otherwise: *what do you think the string should be instead*, and why? Also: which string do you think it's complaining about? (Did you **try to read and understand** the error message?) Did you **check** its value?

Comment: "However, when I try to convert a number like "3.9" to float form" **Clearly**, that isn't what's actually happening - since if you try the code `float("3.9")` by itself, you don't get that error message. Right? So. What the error has told you is that what's being provided **isn't** text like `3.9`. The next step is to figure out **why**. This is a process called **debugging**, and it is not a service Stack Overflow provides. Instead, we answer whatever **question** remains, after **you** [attempt debugging](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Please also read [mre]. Appropriate questions here need to show code that is *focused on the specific* part that is *directly causing the problem* (it is your responsibility to figure out which part that it, and to make sure that others can copy and paste the code, without changing anything, to *directly* see the *exact* problem described in the question).

Answer (score 0):

Oops, just fixed my own question with the code below:

```
def averageSpeed():
    count = 0
    total = 0
    stripLst = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz$'
    while count < 2:
        try:
            filename = input("Enter a file to process: ")
            instance = open(filename, "r")
            content = instance.readlines()
            for line in content:
                print(line)
            print()
            for line in content:
                lineSplit = line.split()
                for element in lineSplit:
                    for letter in element:
                        for character in stripLst:
                            if letter == character:
                                lineSplit.remove(element)
                for element in lineSplit:
                    if float(element) > 2:
                        total += float(element)
                        count += 1
                print(lineSplit)
            average = total / count
            print("The total of the speeds of {} excluding all speeds with lettres in them is {}.".format(filename, total))
            print("The total number of speeds in {} without letters is {}.".format(filename, count))
            print("The average of the speeds of {} excluding all speeds with letters in them is {}.".format(filename, average))
            break
        except (FileNotFoundError):
            print("That file does not exist.")
            count += 1
            filename = input("Enter a file name that exists: ")

averageSpeed()
```

Comment: You might want to add some explanation of what was wrong and how you fixed it. 
Additional suggestion:  When you loop over the letters in the element, instead of then looping over all characters in `stripLst` and then comparing it against the character, just do `if letter in stripList:`
   You might want to learn the re module, as it could handle finding all valid matches for you with a pattern such as `pattern = re.compile(r"\b(\d+(?:\.{1}\d+))\b")` and then extracting all of the matched groups.

Comment: @nigh_anxiety the problem was apparently caused by a typo (or comparably minor oversight - there was a loop iterating over characters of the string, that should have iterated over the already-split words in `lineSplit`), so the question is not appropriate for the site in the first place.